# Include Error on external server

Tags: php, server, pear

I'm putting my web service on a paid external server (with MySQL DB) but when I try to connect it says:

include(DB_Connect.php)[..] failed to open stream: No such file or directory
include() [..] Failed opening 'DB_Connect.php' fot inclusion (include_path='.;C\php5\pear)

I've developed my web service with XAMPP and PHPStorm on my host and I need to upload it on this server (With php 5.5). 
I'm using PHP object oriented and I do not think I've used PEAR functions.
So how can I delete this inclusion? 
Thanks

EDIT:
It works on my localhost

Code: DB_Function.php

```
    include ("Coordinates.php");
include ("DB_Connect.php");

class DB_Functions {

    private $conn;

    // constructor
    function __construct() {

        // connecting to database

        $db = new Db_Connect();
        $this->conn = $db->connect();

    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {}
..
..
```

DB_Connect.php

```
<?php
include ("./Config.php");

/**
 * A class file to connect to database
 */
class DB_CONNECT {

    private $conn;
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
        // connecting to database
        $this->connect();
    }

    // destructor
    function __destruct() {
    }

    /**
     * Function to connect with database
     */
    function connect() {
        // import database connection variables


        // Connecting to mysql database
        $this->conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_DATABASE);

        // returing connection cursor
        return $this->conn;
    }

    /**
     * Function to close db connection
     */


}
```

Also from DB_connect the inclusion of Config.php give the same error, and in that file there are only the definitions of DB constants

Comment: It works totally fine on your localhost? this error means that the DB_Connect.php file is not there, can you post the code part where you include the DB_Connect.php file.

Comment: edited, thanks for the help

Comment: are `DB_Function.php` and `DB_Connect.php` in the same folder?

Comment: yes, also on the server ServerIP/timbrature/*all my files*